# Change type definitions version of compiled module

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have made a package that uses Typescript lib [Exclude and Required](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1418-L1423). When I use this package in an Environment with a recent Typescript version it works ok. I tried to use it on an old Ionic 3 project that uses Typescript `~2.6.2` (Ionic 3 does not support `2.7`) the app breaks because typescript does not understand:

> Cannot find name 'Exclude'.

```
export declare type LoggerTypesObjectForColors = {
    [key in Exclude<LoggerTypesEnum, LoggerTypesEnum.dir>]?: string;
};
```

> Cannot find name 'Required'.

```
 export declare type RequiredLoggerConfig = Required<ILoggerConfig>;
```

Is there a way to *downgrade* the type definitions? (or similar actions)

Edit: If I polyfill `Required` it also breaks

[image]

I was able to do  `Remove` Map thanks to [this article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2017/11/typescript-mighty-morphing-mapped-types/)

```
declare type Remove<T extends string, U extends string> = ({ [P in T]: P } & { [P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
```

An I am trying to make a `Required`. Right now I have this:

```
declare type MakeRequired<T, K extends string> = {
  [P in K]: string
}
```

But I need a way to get the type of T[P] or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not possible since both `Required` and `Exclude` rely on [features added in TypeScript 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html) (*improved control over mapped type modifiers* and *conditional types*, respectively). If TypeScript 2.6 is used by your consumers, you cannot give them definitions that use these features.

However, this doesn't mean your consumers using modern versions of TypeScript should suffer. In order to make your types compliant with legacy versions, ship two versions of types with your package — a modern one and a legacy one.

**Modern TypeScript**

Build them just as you are building them now.

**Legacy versions of TypeScript**

You won't have `Required`, but you should be able to achieve a similar result with legacy versions of `Diff` and `Omit.

```
type Diff<T extends string, U extends string> = ({[P in T]: P } & {[P in U]: never } & { [x: string]: never })[T];
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = {[P in Diff<keyof T, K>]: T[P]};
```

**Shipping two versions of types**

To bundle more than version of typings, add a field called `typesVersions` for your `package.json`. For example:

```
    "types": "index.d.ts",
    "typesVersions": {
        "<=2.8.0-0": {
            "*": [
                "types-legacy/*"
            ]
        }
    },
```

You can read more about bundling multiple version of types [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html).

Comment: Actually when I polyfill Required it also breaks (maybe because of the `-?` ? )

Comment: That's correct, I forgot they were added in 2.8 as well.

Comment: That means that I should manually make a definition for legacy typescript, don't I?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately.